# Emulator in Android Studio won't load

Tags: java, android, exception, android-studio

> Rendering problems. The following classes could not be instantiated: 
>      - android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout .
>
> Exception Details:
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>      android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr

^^^^^------- (The character represented by the '$' is another character I am unable to write. )

This is what shows up instead of my emulator in android studio. I deleted some projects before this happened and may have mistakenly edited a read-only file.  I already tried reinstalling Android Studio and the Android SDK from scratch. Same result. Sometimes it will give an error related to utf-8 and give the option to open up the file encoding. It isn't doing that right now. This brings back the emulator but the drag and drop brings up a small window that can be changed on the emulator. And the problem comes back every time I restart Android Studio.

Is there anything I can do to fix this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to change apptheme? I know some rendering problems or error can be temporarliy fixed by doing this.

Try changing your base application theme using below code - in res/values/styles.xml

It seems to have fixed it for some people. It is also a bugg that will be fixed in a later version. Check the link for more info and some workarounds.

http://tools.android.com/knownissues#TOC-Can-t-Render-Layouts-in-Android-Studio-1.2